# How to handle SpaceBar pressed event in JavaFx when other buttons also there is the same screen

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFx and facing below issue.

I have one JavaFx screen and on that some buttons are there. when I launched application and pressed spacebar, one event is fired associated with one the button exist on the screen. I want when Spacebar is pressed then only event should fire associated with Spacebar.

help will be must appreciated!!!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) that highlights the issue you are having so we can assist better

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest would be to add a check for the spacebar at the beginning of your button's event. If the check passes, the action method returns, doing nothing with it. Then the space event will propagate up to whatever you're using it for.

Comment: @Zircon - Thanks for you solution, but my screen having lots of button so each place have to add that check.. :( looking for more solutions.